# git rebase merge conflict mistake, selected deleted instead of created file

Tags: git, rebase, recovery, merge-conflict-resolution, revision-history

During a `git rebase origin/main` I ran into a merge conflict. A file did not exists in the local branch but in the main branch.
I then ran `git mergetool` and it asked me what I want to do:

```
Merging:
src/CMakeLists.txt

Deleted merge conflict for 'src/CMakeLists.txt':
  {local}: created file
  {remote}: deleted
Use (c)reated or (d)eleted file, or (a)bort? d
```

I selected *(d)eleted file*, which was wrong.
After I continued the rebase I found that the file was missing.

I then checkout out the missing file using `git checkout origin/main src/CMakeLists.txt`, so I could recover the file.
However, the commit history now has an unintended additional commit which may lead to problems if further rebases may be necessary.
I would merely like to undo my decision so that the commit history would be the same as if I had selected the correct answer in the first place.

Comment: Haven't tried but try to check git reflog. Then checkout to last know correct commit.

Comment: Why don't you squash the additional unwanted commit which restores the file onto the commit where you made the wrong choice?

Comment: Because of that: *KONFLIKT (umbenennen/löschen): src/CMakeLists.txt.orig gelöscht in Some commit msg[..] und umbenannt nach src/CMakeLists.txt in HEAD. Stand HEAD von src/CMakeLists.txt wurde im Arbeitsbereich gelassen.*. It seems: Git thought I renamed the file because I deleted a similar named file. Although the file was there all the time. And after that I made that silly mistake selecting the deleted file. I have the commit hash 564d590f0ce4a8c1c4d7a3be27a96c2202fc610f but it was not the latest commit during the rebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just about keeping the `origin/master` version of `CMakeLists.txt` through all your history :

- run `git rebase -i origin/master`
- in the list of actions, add a `break` instruction right after the first commit, save & exit
- when `git rebase` stops, run

  ```
  git checkout origin/main -- src/CMakeLists.txt
  git commit --amend
  ```
- run `git rebase --continue`
- if you have conflicts on that file, you know can always run `git checkout origin/master -- src/CMakeLists.txt` to restore that version
- you may have `git rebase` stopping because there are no changes left for a particular commit, in that case run `git rebase --skip` to skip replaying that commit

---

If, on the other hand, you had modifications on that file which you want to preserve and restore :

- inspect your reflog : `git reflog` or `git reflog my/working/branch`
- spot the state of your branch *before* you ran `git rebase`
- return to that point : `git reset --hard <sha>`
- run `git rebase origin/master` again

---

A generic warning on `git reset --hard` :
run it on a clean worktree, it is one of the very few commands in git that can remove some files or modifications from your disk without them being stored in git.